# How to rewrite these queries as a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, denormalization

I am denormalizing a lot of data for speed reasons.

I have a table that I first join to another table and group on two fields to calculate some aggregates. Then I group this table on one of the fields, calculate some more aggregates then merge these two together.

```
INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT
  t1.field1,
  t2.field2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.field3) AS field3
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ...
GROUP BY t1.field1,t2.field2

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
SELECT
  field1,
  SUM(IF(fa='constant',1,0)) AS fa
FROM table1
GROUP BY field1;

UPDATE final_table
INNER JOIN tmp ON tmp.field1 = final_table.field1
SET final_table.fa = tmp.fa
```

I really would like to rewrite this as a single query (with some subqueries I guess) -- the problem is obviously that the first query contains a join and so every row from the first table will occur many times (as the second table dictates) completely breaking my little pivot counter in the second query.

Comment: First query is not doing Cartesian product since you have joining condition. Cartesian product is either `CROSS JOIN` or `JOIN ON 1` (so each with each)

Comment: OK, removed that. I think it does a Cartesian product then a restriction (σ) on the resulting set, but that's immaterial to the question :)

Comment: I think we need to know the cardinality of your data.  There's at least 3 or 4 different options, depending on what your data is and what you need it to look like...  what makes you think you need to denormalize?